# Plotting multiple graphs based on data groups using par function

Tags: r, plot, subset, par

I need to plot 4 plots in R, with position on the x-axis and and number of marbles on the y-axis. There are four groups in the data, and are unique according to the `Set` and `Block`.

Right now, I am sub-setting each data according to `Block` and plotting it. After which I use the `par()` function to plot them all together.

Is there an easy way to plot the data without subsetting them manually?

```
  Set Size    Position  Marbles Block
   1   Small  1         8        1
   1   Small  2         81       1
   1   Small  3         3        1
   1   Small  4         4        1
   4   Small  1         8        1
   4   Small  2         81       1
   4   Small  3         3        1
   4   Small  4         4        1
   4   Small  1         14       2
   6   Small  2         11       2
   6   Small  3         12       2
   6   Small  4         25       2
   1   Small  1         8        3
   1   Small  2         81       3
   1   Small  3         3        3
   1   Small  4         4        3
   6   Small  1         14       4
   6   Small  2         11       4
   6   Small  3         12       4
   6   Small  4         25       4
```

Comment: If someone is going to downvote it, you should atleast have the goodwilll to reason it out

Comment: I did not down vote it but you should include your current code to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ggplot2::facet_wrap()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = Position, y = Marbles)) + 
       geom_point() + facet_wrap(~Block)
```

[image]

***Data:***

```
 dat <- structure(list(Set = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L,                 
     1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Size = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,                   
     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Small", class = "factor"), 
         Position = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L,                      
         4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Marbles = c(8L, 81L, 3L, 4L, 14L, 11L,                   
         12L, 25L, 8L, 81L, 3L, 4L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 25L), Block = c(1L,                 
         1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L                    
         )), .Names = c("Set", "Size", "Position", "Marbles", "Block"                  
     ), row.names = c(NA, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is useful. But if I have multiple sets within my block, I need to subset it again. Anyway to get around that?

Comment: @Ash `facet_wrap(~Block+Set)` for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using `par` and base `plot`.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
by(d, d$Block, function(b) plot(Marbles ~ Position, b, ylim=c(0, max(d$Marbles)), 
                                main=unique(b$Block)))
par(op)
```

[image]

---

*Data*

```
d <- structure(list(Set = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Size = c("Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", 
"Small", "Small", "Small", "Small"), Position = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L), Marbles = c(8L, 81L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 81L, 3L, 4L, 14L, 11L, 
12L, 25L, 8L, 81L, 3L, 4L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 25L), Block = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```